# getting error when trying to pass pipeline secret variable into Powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to pass a secret variable into a Powershell script as part of an Azure pipeline. I added the variable by going to 'Edit Pipeline', then clicking on the Variables button, adding the variable and selecting 'Keep this value secret' checkbox. The variable name is PAT.

I reference the variable in the Powershell script, which is a separate file, like this:

```
$url = '[Azure DevOps url]'
<# pass PAT as pipeline variable #>
$Token = "$env:PATSECRET"

if ($PAT -eq "") {
    exit 1
}
$AzureAuthHeader = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $Token)))

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", ("Basic {0}" -f $AzureAuthHeader))
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $headers

$lastcommit = $response.value[1].commitId

$packageFolder = git diff HEAD $lastcommit --name-only
```

Here is the Powershell script build step in the pipeline:

```
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Detect Subfolder Changes'
    name: setvarStep
    env:
      Pat: $(PAT)
    inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\detectchanges.ps1
      failOnStderr: true
```

When the pipeline runs I get this error: `##[error]env:PAT : The term 'env:PAT' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program ...`

UPDATE:
I updated the Powershell build step with the environmental variable mapping. I'm still getting the same error. I also removed the parentheses around `$(env:PAT)` and there was no change.

Comment: Please also share your PowerShell script if you still have issues.

Comment: Please make sure the variable names are the same. I used Rest API with PAT in PowerShell script and worked well. Please check the sample in my answer. In addition, which agent are you using? Please try to use other [vmImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the script's environment or map the variable within the variables block to pass secrets to your pipeline. Here are my samples:

1.Script's environment(Recommended way):

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Detect Subfolder Changes'
  name: setvarStep
  env:
    MY_PAT: $(PAT)
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test.ps1'
    failOnStderr: true
```

test.ps1:

```
$token= "$env:MY_PAT"
if ($token -eq "") {
    exit 1
}
 
$url= "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.1-preview.2"

$AzureAuthHeader = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $Token)))

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", ("Basic {0}" -f $AzureAuthHeader))
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
 
$JSON = @'
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task' AND [State] <> 'Closed' AND [State] <> 'Removed' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}
'@
 
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
Write-Host "result = $($response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

2.Variables definition

```
variables:
  MY_PAT: $(PAT)
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "PAT: $(MY_PAT)"
```

You  can find more detailed information in this document about [set secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables).

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks. Part of my problem was not having the correct naming of the variable in the build step.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft "secret variables are not automatically mapped. If you have a secret variable called Foo, you can map it in like this":

```
- powershell: echo $env:MYSECRET
  env:
    MySecret: $(Foo)
```